Users can only see/edit their own entry list: User can no longer view or edit their entry!
I have a list where users can only see and edit their own entry.  2 users cannot view their entry (let alone edit it) anymore.  The page is "blank" -  it has the name of the list for them, and the column list names but their entry is not showing.  They are there as I can see it as admin.
I have checked permissions and their permissions are all the same as everyone else - nothing has changed.
They are both definitely the creators of their entry - the entries are 2 years old or more so they have successfully used them up to this point.
Am I missing anything to check?  Or any advice to solve this?
Thanks for the help.

Maybe they have their accounts recreated so their SPUser IDs are different from that specified as Authors of that entries? Just to check, try to give them Full control permission on list temporarily and see if it helps - to make sure that permission is the issue.
